# Weights on a lever

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I had a very simple question that I just wanted to make sure of.

I remember from my A Level physics that the further something is away from the fulcrum, the larger the torque (the weight multiplied by the distance from the fulcrum). However I don't remember ever covering anything that had both forces on the same side of the fulcrum, and in opposite directions.

To give some more context, I've been asked to design some way to add weight to a hydraulic cylinder, so that the hydraulic pumps can be properly tested before being used. Here is a crudely drawn picture of my idea, far from the engineering drawing that my tutor would want me to do.

[image: Forces]

Am I right in thinking that, not including the weight of the bar itself. If the cylinder pushes up half way between the weight and the pivot, it would see twice the force? So a 200KG weight on the end would test the pump as though it had 400KG on it? Is there any corrections I would have to do based on the angle to get the actual vertical force?

I'm sure this question is a lot simpler than the usual things posted here but I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Am I right in thinking that, not including the weight of the bar itself. If the cylinder pushes up half way between the weight and the pivot, it would see twice the force? So a 200KG weight on the end would test the pump as though it had 400KG on it?*

Based on your diagram, this is all correct.

*Is there any corrections I would have to do based on the angle to get the actual vertical force?*

Assuming the bar is close to horizontal, then no. If the angle of the bar were not negligible, there would be a component of the weight of the end mass that would end up being supported axially through the bar and (presumably) through the pivot point and whatever that may be attached to.